# Working with a large amount of data

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I got c# appliaction and `entity famework` as ORM.
I got database with table `Images`. Table have `Id`, `TimeStamp`, `Data` columns.
This table can have really ALOT entities. Also `Data`column contain large byte array.
I need to take first entity starting from some date, or first 5 as example.

```
var result = Images.OrderBy(img => img.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault(img => img.TimeStamp > someDate);
```

throws out of memory exception. 
Is there some way to pass that?
Should i use stored procedure or something else?

Comment: Take a look at to the Indexes, create one that is sorted by TimeStamp and make select operations from that index.

Comment: Isn't it that Images is a materialized list of objects? Then I could understand why it throws Out of memory exception when you try to sort.

Comment: You can also mark those columns with large data in them as virtual.

Comment: Use [table splitting](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/splitting-tables.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Images` is already a queried object, then when you `OrderBy` it, it accesses the whole set. I'll assume it isn't, and it is directly your `DbSet` or an EF `IQueryable` (so you are querying using Linq-To-Entities and not Linq-To-Objects and the ordering is done on the query to the database, and not on the returned whole set).

Unless you need change tracking detection, use `AsNoTracking` on your `DbSet` (in this case, `Context.Images.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(...)`. That should lower the memory requirements by a lot (change tracking detection requires more than twice the memory).

Also, if using large blob data, it might be wise to store it in its own table (with just an `id` and the `data`) and access it only when you need it (having a reference to this `id` on the table/entity where you are doing your operations) if you are using an ORM and want to work with the original entity all the time (you could also use a `Select` to project the query on a new entity without the blob field).

If you **need** to access the image data for the returned rows all the time, and there's not enough memory in the system for it, then tough luck.